# Tracking HttpClient.PostAsync progress using Blazor and Aspnet Webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, progress-bar, blazor, dotnet-httpclient

I am currently using Blazor and Asp.Net WebApi Controller to perform some file upload/download..And I have a UploadFiles() called in the Blazor client that looks like this:

```
public async Task<bool> UploadFiles(Action<int> callback, IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> files, string subdir = "")
{
    if (files != null)
    {
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fileContent = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream(_allowedMaxFileSize));
            content.Add(fileContent, "\"files\"", file.Name);  
            hasItemsForUpload = true;
        }

        if (content != null)
        {
            var uri = $@"api/mycontroller/upload?subdir=" + subdir;
            var result = await _http.PostAsync(uri, content);

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {                       
                return true;
            }
        }
    }    

    return false;
}
```

Is there a way for me to easily track httpclient.postasync() % progress where I can pass the % as int in my callback? Note that `_http` here is injected through dependency injection registered as AddScope() of the startup.cs

I've seen complicated examples using custom http content but I can't seem to wrap my head around it... :(

Please help..

Comment: Do you want to track the progress of a single http request or the batch upload as a whole?

Comment: Hi @MayurEkbote, to keep things simple, I am okay with tracking the http request as a whole, no need to track each file... :)

Comment: Is there a constraint on making one http request for one file? It will also make reporting progress straightforward.

Comment: @MayurEkbote no constraint, it will be okay also if one file per one http request...please teach me how to do it with progress tracking?

Answer (score 0):

FileComponent.razor

```
<div> Progress: @current </div>

@code
{
  int current = 0;
  
  void UpdateProgress()
  {
    current++;
    StateHasChanged();
  }
  void ResetBatch(){ current=0; }

  
  public async Task<bool> UploadFiles(Action<int> callback, IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> files, string subdir = "")
{
    ResetBatch();
    if (files != null)
    {
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fileContent = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream(_allowedMaxFileSize));
            content.Add(fileContent, "\"files\"", file.Name);  
            hasItemsForUpload = true;
        if (content != null)
        {
            var uri = $@"api/mycontroller/upload?subdir=" + subdir;
            var result = await _http.PostAsync(uri, content);
        
         }

         UpdateProgress();
        }
    }    
    ResetBatch();
    return true;
}
}
```

Note that instead of 'current' you can create a whole upload batch class that contains information regarding total files to be updated, filenames, current file name, status of each upload etc etc.